# Delete everyting preceding and including a certain substring from variable

Tags: bash, sed, cut

In Bash, how can I delete characters from a variable until a certain substring?

Example:

```
ananas1kiwi2apple1banana2tree
```

shall look like this:

```
apple1banana2tree
```

The substring in this case is `2`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to remove the substring upto `2`, using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
${var#*2}
```

- `#` does non-greedy match from left, use `##` for greediness
- `#*2` matches and discards upto first `2` from variable `var`

**Example:**

```
$ var='ananas1kiwi2apple1banana2tree'
$ echo "${var#*2}"
apple1banana2tree
```

Answer (score 6):

Using pure `bash` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
$ string="ananas1kiwi2apple1banana2tree"
$ newString="${string#*2}"
$ printf "%s\n" "$newString"
apple1banana2tree
```